# Outlook 2010: is there a way to view multiple IMAP mail accounts in one folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a lot of email addresses, because I run a small businesses and have them separated by role. I choose to use IMAP; however, this means that the messages are never moved into the outlook "Personal Folder." Is there a way to establish a view that's simply all the mail from my many accounts, in one list, whether or not it's the Personal Folder?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using IMAP if you have the option to leave messages on the server, as IMAP has a synchronization methodology.

Comment: Fine, forget that part. I'm most certainly using IMAP. Do you know anything about how to accomplish the configuration I'm talking about?

Answer (score 1):

When you set up your e-mail accounts to begin with, POP accounts have the option of being delivered to the folder of your choice.  Unfortunately, when you select an IMAP account, that option dissapears.  That should be the way to do it, but it doesn't work for IMAP...

The closest I've been able to come to viewing all my IMAP mail in one folder in Outlook, is through the Search functions.

First, set your options to allow Search to check all your folders. Go to File>Options, and click on "Search" options.  Under "Results", click radio button "All folders", then "Ok", so search will look in all your folders for mail.

Now from your "Home" tab, hit Ctrl + E, to bring up your "Search" tab and menus.  In the "Refine" column, you can click "unread", and it will search all your folders for unread e-mail.  Alternately you can click the "This week" button or sub options to find all messages you've received in the past week, etc.

You can also kind of get what you want with rules.  For every IMAP account, make a rule to forward a copy to your personal folder when messages arrive through a specified account.  The problem with this is that for some reason, rules assumes that every automatic filter will be applied "after the message arrives".  But since IMAP keeps track of message status between all your clients, and since you may read some of your IMAP email from another application like your cell phone, any mail you've read in another client will register as already having arrived and having been read when it gets to your Outlook.  Thus, any mail you've already read will bypass the filter without moving a copy.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, I have the same problem with @bewerks and I don't really think we want to "move or copy" email. What we want is a unified view - "Search Folder", for inboxes from few IMAP. However, seem that is not supported in Outlook 2010.

No solution for now until outlook allow search folder across PST files.